# How can I iterate through an array of objects using Entities and functions to make a seeder for TypeORM?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, typeorm, typescript-generics

Using NodeJS and ExpressJS,

I want to iterate through an array of functions in order to generate seeds from my database using TypeORM. I already have an approach to insert multiple records through a function, but it looks kinda messy because of repetitive code. ([gist reference](https://gist.github.com/MiquelVald/46ff4778721f0a35ae508fbd6023ea22))

On my factories file I have functions like these:

```js
const onePropuesta = (id: string = v4()): Propuesta => {

    return {
        id,
        giro: faker.lorem.words(3),
        tipoPropuesta: faker.lorem.words(3),
        predioAPropuesta: [],
    }
};


const fakeMultiple = <T>(options: { times?: number, creator: () => T }): T[] => {
    const { times = 5, creator } = options;
    const arr: T[] = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < times; i++) {
        arr.push(creator());
    }
    return arr;
};
```

I consume these functions to generate a record with TypeORM with this:

```js
await myRepository.save(fakeMultiple({creator: onePropuesta, times: 2}))
```

And this will generate two records for the selected repository.

So my idea was to iterate through the repetitive code:

```js
const seederObjects = [
    {
        repository: UsoDeSuelo,
        creator: oneUsoDeSuelo,
        times: 10,
    },
    {
        repository: Predio,
        creator: onePredio,
        times: 2,
    },
    {
        repository: Propuesta,
        creator: onePropuesta,
        times: 1,
    },
    {
        repository: Promotor,
        creator: onePromotor,
        times: 6,
    },
]

...
        seederObjects.forEach(async (seederObject) => {
            const { repository, creator, times } = seederObject;
            const entityRepository = appDataSource.getRepository(repository);

            const entities = await entityRepository.save(fakeMultiple({
                creator,
                times,
            }));

        });
...
```

But i'm getting an error that says that the Type of creator is not assignable:

[image: Error message for iteration of array of objects]

I'd like to know what I'm doing wrong, and probably it's because of the array types, but I'm not certain.